# excel macro: ByRef argument type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

i write a code as follow:

```
Call search(xx, yy, "APM Output", ">> State Scalars", label1)

label1:
      ...........
```

this the script of Sub search

```
Sub search(row As Variant, col As Variant, wkst As String, str As String, label_num As Name)
For row = 1 To 100
  For col = 1 To 100
    strTemp = Worksheets(wkst).Cells(row, col).Value
    If InStr(strTemp, str) <> 0 Then
        GoTo label_num
    End If
  Next
Next
End Sub
```

i want to call sub search(..) firstly, and then go to label1.
The problem is that is says that "ByRef argument type mismatch" for label_num.What should be the correct type for label_num in Sub search(..,..,..,**label_num**)?

i add some original script, these are what I want to convert into a sub()

```
For xx = 1 To 100
    For yy = 1 To 100
        strTemp = Worksheets("APM Output").Cells(xx, yy).Value
        If InStr(strTemp, ">> State Scalars") <> 0 Then
            GoTo label1
        End If
    Next
Next
label1:
    For uu = 1 To 100
        For vv = 1 To 100
            strTemp = Worksheets("APM Output").Cells(uu, vv).Value
            If InStr(strTemp, ">> GPU LPML") <> 0 Then
                GoTo label2
            End If
        Next
    Next
label2:
    For mm = 1 To 100
        For nn = 1 To 100
            strTemp = Worksheets("APM Output").Cells(mm, nn).Value
            If InStr(strTemp, ">> Limits and Equations") <> 0 Then
                GoTo label3
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Label1 isn't a `Name`. Hence your error. But even then, you can't use it this way to exit one sub, and go straight to a defined position in the second sub

Comment: oh, i see. by the way, could u give me some suggestion how to write this sub? i add my script, and I test already, they can run without problem. I want to summarize them into a call sub()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a good practise, please avoid using label at all cost!

I am going to answer you just modifying your code, I guess you want to save the values of 
xx,yy,uu,vv,mm,nn

the following code is how to avoid using label

```
Dim found1 As Boolean
Dim found2  As Boolean
Dim found3 As Boolean
  found1 = False
  found2 = False
  found3 = False
  For i = 1 To 100
   For j = 1 To 100
       strTemp = Worksheets("APM Output").Cells(i, j).Value
       If InStr(strTemp, ">> State Scalars") <> 0 And Not found1 Then
           found1 = True
           xx = i
           yy = j
       End If

       If InStr(strTemp, ">> GPU LPML") <> 0 And Not found2 Then
           found2 = True
           uu = i
           vv = j
       End If
       If InStr(strTemp, ">> Limits and Equations") <> 0 And Not found3 Then
           found3 = True
           mm = i
           nn = j
       End If
   Next j
Next i
```

to make your function into a sub, simply do

```
Sub my_search(ByRef rowNum As Long, ByRef colNum As Long, ByVal searchString As String, ByVal height As Long, ByVal width As Long, ByRef ws As Worksheet)
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim found As Boolean
found = False
Dim strTemp
With ws
    For i = 1 To height 
       For j = 1 To width 
           strTemp = ws.Cells(i, j).Value
           If InStr(strTemp, searchString ) <> 0 And Not found1 Then
               found = True
               rowNum = i 'assigning rowNum 
               colNum = j 'assigning colNum
               Exit For
           End If
       Next j
       If found Then
        Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End With
End Sub
```

and call it 3 times, 
for example:

```
my_search xx,yy,">>State Scalars", 100, 100, Worksheets("APM Output")
```

Answer (score 3):

Your sub doesn't make much sense to me as

1. if it finds `">> State Scalars"` it exist the `For` loop and goes to `label1`
2. if it doesn't  find `">> State Scalars"` reaches `label1` anyway

You could use the code below

- searches your 100 by 100 cell range in a single shot
- either finds your partial string match or doesn't
- it could be easily modified to stop searching after a successful (or failed) search

**`code`**

```
Sub ReCut()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = Worksheets("APM Output").Range("A1:CV100")
Set rng1 = rng2.Find(">> State Scalars", , xlValues, xlPart)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Found >> State Scalars value at " & rng1.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine & "This is the equivalent of your exit on INSTR"
Else
End If
Set rng1 = rng2.Find(">> GPU LPML", , xlValues, xlPart)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Found >> GPU LPML value at " & rng1.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine & "This is the equivalent of your exit on INSTR"
Else
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 . I agree. `.Find` is much faster :)