# excel macro: summarize the code into call sub()

Tags: vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [excel macro: ByRef argument type mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506248/excel-macro-byref-argument-type-mismatch)

i write a code as follow:

```
For xx = 1 To 100
    For yy = 1 To 100
        strTemp = Worksheets("APM Output").Cells(xx, yy).Value
        If InStr(strTemp, ">> State Scalars") <> 0 Then
            GoTo label1
        End If
    Next
Next
label1:
    For uu = 1 To 100
        For vv = 1 To 100
            strTemp = Worksheets("APM Output").Cells(uu, vv).Value
            If InStr(strTemp, ">> GPU LPML") <> 0 Then
                GoTo label2
            End If
        Next
    Next
label2:
    For mm = 1 To 100
        For nn = 1 To 100
            strTemp = Worksheets("APM Output").Cells(mm, nn).Value
            If InStr(strTemp, ">> Limits and Equations") <> 0 Then
                GoTo label3
            End If
        Next
    Next
....
```

I want to summarize them into a new sub(...) to call, but it has mistake after I test it.

```
Sub search(row As Variant, col As Variant, wkst As String, str As String, label_num As Name) 

For row = 1 To 100   
  For col = 1 To 100     
    strTemp = Worksheets(wkst).Cells(row, col).Value     
    If InStr(strTemp, str) <> 0 Then         
      GoTo label_num     
    End If   
  Next 
Next 

End Sub
```

How to modify it? I really need some suggestion.thx

Comment: I see in your summary function, you have `goto label_num` but there's no `label_num:` for it to go to  *(GoTo can branch only to lines within the procedure where it appears.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a good programming practice to split recurrent parts of a sub in a separate function

I would personally go into the following route:

```
Sub Subroutine()
    set tCell = UDF_FindValue("APM Output",">> State Scalars")
    set tCell = UDF_FindValue("APM Output",">> GPU LPML")
    set tCell = UDF_FindValue("APM Output",">> Limits and Equations")
End Sub

Function UDF_FindValue(WS_Name as String, SearchString as String) as Range
    Set RefWS = WorkSheets(WS_Name)
    for each sCell in intersect(RefWS.Rows("1:100"),RefWS.Columns("1:100"))
        if sCell.value = SearchString then
            Set UDF_FindValue = sCell
            End function
        end if
    next sCell
End Function
```

if you make your function general enough, you can also re-use it later...

it will also enable you to modify your code easily, if, by example, you find out that the find function already does what you want...